# read unequal lines into vector of vector

Tags: c++

I have found several similar questions to read file line by line [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22562221/read-adjacency-list-of-digraph-from-a-text-file-in-c),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868936/read-file-line-by-line-using-ifstream-in-c), I tried to  follow them but it seems my code does not work correctly.

here is my try:

**Input file**

0   3   5   7
1   5   6   7   9
2   3   6   7   8
3   0   2   7   9
4   6   8
5   0   1   7
6   1   2   4   9
7   0   1   2   3   5   8
8   2   4   7
9   1   3   6

**The code**

```
int main() {

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> a;
    a.resize(10);

    std::string filename = "data/a.adjlist";

    std::ifstream file(filename);
    if (file.is_open()) {
        std::string line;
        int counter = 0;

        while (getline(file, line)) {
            printf("%s \n", line.c_str());
            std::istringstream iss(line);
            int value;
            while(iss >> value) 
                a[counter].push_back(value);
            counter ++;
        }
    }
    file.close();
    for (int i=0; i<a.size(); i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<a[0].size(); j++) {
            cout << a[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }

}
```

**Output**

0 3 5 7
1 5 6 7
2 3 6 7
3 0 2 7
4 6 8 7
5 0 1 7
6 1 2 4
7 0 1 2
8 2 4 7
9 1 3 6

Comment: `for (int j=0; j<a[0].size(); j++)` , did you mean `for (int j=0; j<a[i].size(); j++)` ?

Comment: yeah got it! thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int j=0; j<a[0].size() ; j++)
```

should be

```
for (int j=0; j<a[i].size(); j++)
```

Safer, removes you the need to fiddle with indices:

```
   for (auto& aa : a) {
        for (auto& b : aa) {
            cout << b << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
```